# Outlook Web Add-in Blazor and OnMessageSend

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've seen and followed the sample for creating an Outlook Web Add-in using Blazor for a TaskPane add-in.  I've tried adapting it to work with the `OnMessageSend` event of web add-ins.  I've hit a wall though trying to get it to load.  From what I can tell, the main difference between a TaskPane and `OnMessageSend` add-in that stops this from working is that a TaskPane add-in requires an HTML endpoint to be invoked/called and the `OnMessageSend` add-in requires a JavaScript function.  It seems there's no way to configure this.

Am I missing something obvious that would enable a web add-in targeting the OnMessageSend feature to use Blazor or WASM?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your question on Blazor Outlook Addin Repo(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/blazor-add-in/outlook-blazor-add-in) and concerned team should be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT.  Asked [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/issues/578)